# mosquitto bridge resend message at reconnect

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, qos

Im publishing mqtt messages from machine1 to machine2 through a bridge. On machine1 Im running mosquitto broker and on machine2 Im using rabbitmq mqtt plugin.

Im trying to hold messages in case of network disconnection. When it connects again it should retry sending the messages. I set cleansession to false and QoS at the bridge to 1 However Im not receiving the messages

here is the bridge configuration

```
connection main
address <ipAddress>:1883
topic # both 1 topic1/ topic2/
cleansession false
try_private false
remote_username <username>
remote_password <password>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: What QOS are you publishing the actual messages at? How are you disconnecting the 2 brokers for the test?

Comment: i was putting the QoS only on the bridge connection configuration it is working now after  I publish the msg with QoS 1 .. for testing Im disabling the network adapter at the remote machine then enable it after some time .. thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

should publish msgs using QoS 1 using -q option

```
mosquitto_pub -q 1 -t ubuntuTopics/test/ -m "TESTING"
```